# Using Libgdx seek behaviour with box2d?

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, behavior

I'm trying to implement the seek behaviour of Libgdx using Box2d to actually move the body onscreen.
I understand how the seek behaviour works and have my two object classes which implement the Steerable interface. I have looked at the Seek class and I don't quite understand how SteeringAcceleration works with it.

At the moment I have(these are the relevant bits):
In my game/rendering/main world class:

```
//fields
Seek<Vector2> s;
Object a;
Object b;

//constructer
s = new Seek<Vector2>(b,a);
    s.setEnabled(true);

//run
s.calculateSteering(//not sure what to put here for SteeringAcceleration param?);
```

In my Object classes:

```
public float getMaxAngularAcceleration() {
    return 5;//not sure what to put here yet
}

@Override
public Vector2 getPosition() {
    return new Vector2(sprite.getX(), sprite.getY());
}
```

^^These seem to be the only methods of Steerable I need to change for Seek.

I have read the libgdx tutorial on behaviours and I understand them in theory but I can't for the life of me figure out how to put it all together in code. I know I must need to apply a force or impulse to the body to get it to actually go where calculateSteering tells it but I don't know where to perform that and what exactly to put in the parameter of calculate steering. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SteeringAcceleration is just a class that holds the linear and angular acceleration that the seek behavior has calculated.

```
SteeringAcceleration<Vector2> steerAcc = new SteeringAcceleration<Vector2>();
s.calculateSteering(steerAcc);
```

Then in your update method you apply the acceleration values that is in SteeringAcceleration to the box2d body.

```
body.applyLinearImpulse(steerAcc.linear.scl(deltaTime), pos, true);
body.applyAngularImpulse(steerAcc.angular * deltaTime, true);
```

Comment: Thank you, it took a bit of tweaking but it's working!